# How to disable kendo-grid-checkbox-column?

Tags: html, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to disable kendo-grid-checkbox-column?

I have tried

- `[disabled]="true"`
- `[attr.disabled]="true"`
- `disabled ="true"`
- `disabled`
- `readonly`

But nothing is helped to disable this below column

```
<kendo-grid-checkbox-column   width="50" showSelectAll="true">
        </kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can produce a disabled checkbox by specifying custom templates and adding a condition to the `[disabled]` attribute.

```
 <kendo-grid-checkbox-column width="80"  [locked]="true">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex" >

        <input  *ngIf="!dataItem.IsNew"
                [disabled]="dataItem.IsNew === true"
                type="checkbox"
                class="k-checkbox"
                id="checkbox-{{rowIndex}}"
                [kendoGridSelectionCheckbox]="rowIndex"
                />  
        <label class="k-checkbox-label"
            for="checkbox-{{rowIndex}}">
        </label>
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
```

This will render out a Kendo checkbox that will be disabled according to your conditions specified above.

If you want to display a select all checkbox in the header you need to add this template to the checkbox column:

```
       <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate >
            <input kendoGridSelectAllCheckbox type="checkbox"
                class="k-checkbox"
                id="headerCheckbox"
            />
            <label class="k-checkbox-label"
                        for="headerCheckbox"
                ></label>
       </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Grid rowClass input and provide a function that will return the "k-disabled" class (or any other custom class that would prevent the user from interacting with the given row), for all data items that pass some condition, e.g.:

```
public isDisabled(args) {
  return {
       'k-disabled': args.dataItem.UnitsOnOrder === 0
   }; 
}
```

I hope this helps.

========OR========

```
<kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let- 
rowIndex="rowIndex" >
<div class="{{dataItem.UnitsOnOrder === 0 ? 'k-disabled' : ''}}">
  <input [kendoGridSelectionCheckbox]="rowIndex" />
</div>
</ng-template>
```

CSS class was changed from k-disabled to k-state-disabled in recent Kendo UI theme versions

Resource: https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-angular-grid---row-selection

Comment: Error: Can't bind to 'rowClass' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-grid-checkbox-column'.

Comment: I am using `[rowClass]="isDisabled(args)"` in the column

Comment: then install `npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-grid @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns @progress/kendo-angular-inputs @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs @progress/kendo-data-query @progress/kendo-angular-intl @progress/kendo-angular-l10n @progress/kendo-drawing @progress/kendo-angular-excel-export @progress/kendo-angular-buttons` and import the same at app.module.ts

Comment: For Angular 6, install the rxjs-compat package. For more information, refer to the article on upgrading to Angular 6.

`npm install --save rxjs-compat@6`
For Angular 5 or earlier, install RxJS v5.5+.

`npm install --save rxjs@^5.5`

Comment: installed. but still facing the same problem.is this a correct syntex? `[rowClass]="isDisabled(args)"`